# What is the difference between dYdX and other DEX?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereumjs, decentralized-exchange

I have been reading about dydx and didn't find any difference between dydx and other DEX. Please share some links where I can find the difference between dydx and other DEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main different between DYDX and other DEX:

DYDX is the combination of the CEX and the DEX, by using an order book instead of AMM. So besides the swap like Uni or Pancake, DYDX offers the future, margin trading like the traditional CEX.

I found [this article](https://phemex.com/academy/what-is-dydx) is interest to have an overview of what DYDX does.